# Should [modifier] be burninated?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier) tag on Stack Overflow has 414 questions at the time of posting, but the topics it seems to cover vary wildly.

There are questions about [regex modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier%2bregex?tab=Votes), [Android Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier+android-jetpack-compose), [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier+swift), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier+java), [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier+c%23), [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier+javascript), the list goes on...

This is because the term "modifier" is *very* general. It can be applied to problems in all kinds of topics; as such, the tag adds pretty much zero meaning to any post with it.

---

Going through the Burnination criteria:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

A question can be about some kind of modifier, but this tag does nothing to describe what kind of modifier is in question and is 100% ambiguous.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

One could argue that the term "modifier" can be on topic in pretty much any field, and therefore is less on-topic here. (Not sure this is the greatest justification)

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No—as stated above, "modifier" can be applied to a variety of topics, so it doesn't help explain what the question is about.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

Comment: Disagree, as long as its not the ONLY tag, it helps refine what the question is about. Pairing it with, say, regex, indicates that a regex modifier is relevant.

Comment: @Paulie_D: "Pairing it with, say, regex, indicates that a regex modifier is relevant." - Tags are not just words which could be joined into a phrase. A tag is expected to reflect a **concept**, which is **common** among all questions to which that tag is applied. Such *concept* could have some properties, which varies between different languages, frameworks, libraries, but in all of those applications the core of the concept should be the same. I don't see any common concept in questions about regex modifiers and, say, [final modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75738401) in Java.

Comment: It should be burninated, but largely by **retagging** where a relevant tag exists or should exist.  For example, perhaps Jetpack Compose modifiers should have their own tag (disclosure: I worked on Jetpack Compose; just using it as an example since I'm familiar with the concepts).

Comment: Nobody could be expected to be an expert in [tag:modifier] questions. It's a good candidate for removal.